# ActiveRecord for rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to make the following query in ActiveRecord in rails.

```
SELECT * FROM test_run WHERE build = '$build' AND suite='$suite'AND (result = 'fail' OR     result = 'error') 
    AND test_name NOT IN(SELECT test_name FROM test_run WHERE result = 'pass' AND   build  = '$build')GROUP BY test_name";
```

The first part is easy, I am not sure how to do the subquery.

```
scope :never_passed, lambda { |b| where(:build => b, :status => 'fail').where(??)
```

Any ideas on what I would need to do to be able to get this subquery to work as the sql above?

Thanks

Comment: check this out. It should save you some headaches: https://github.com/ernie/squeel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Arel, you can do subqueries like:

```
TestRun.where(:test_name => TestRun.where('result != ? && build != ?','pass','somevalue').select('test_name')).to_sql
```

would output the following SQL:

```
SELECT `test_runs`.* FROM `test_runs` WHERE `test_runs`.`test_name` IN ('test1','test2')
```